# Rails JSON to Swift 2 JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, swift, swift2

I'm trying to share data from my rails web server to a swift app with JSON. I'm struggling to make this connection.

From the Rails controller:

```
    ...
    output = x.to_json
    render :json => output 
    ...
```

In the Swift iOS App:

```
import UIKit
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    reachForWebsite()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
func reachForWebsite(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "myURL")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if let jsonObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error = &error){
            if let dict = jsonObject as? NSDictionary {
                println(dict)
            } else {
                println("not a dictionary")
            }
        } else {
            println("Could not parse JSON: \(error!)")
        }
            println(data.dynamicType)
        }
    }
    task!.resume()
}
}
```

I can verify the I am successfully receiving the data because I can convert it to a string and print it to the console on the app. I am unable however to create an NSDictionary object from it. The errors change with each tinker, but relate to Optionals and try catch.

**JSON**

```
{"inside":[{"name":"BOB"}, ...],"outside":[{"name":"TIM","type":"HUMAN","id":1}, ...],"info":{"time":"2015-07-02"}}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON you are parsing?

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with your JSON format, or perhaps it's an array instead of a dictionary?  Also, this may or not be part of the answer you're looking for, but this is a delightful opportunity to unwrap optionals with a switch case: https://gist.github.com/patricklynch/8d5b792c5fa2aad95fe7

Comment: @PatrickLynch Updated question with JSON format

Comment: Not sure if this will help but try this instead of jsonObject and dict line. Not sure if will work but worth a try -         let jsonresult:NSDictionary = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.bytes, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

Comment: self.bytes is data in your case

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this to parse the JSON with Swift 2

```
guard let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(URL) {(data, response, error) in
guard let data = data, error == nil 
else 
{
    // Checks for errors if the task fails like for bad connectivity.
    print(error);
    return;
}
do 
{
    guard let JSONDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [NSObject: AnyObject] 
    else
    {
        // The JSONDict wasn't a dictionary. Maybe its an array here? If it is change the structure of the parsing.
        print("The JSON wasn't a dictionary. Try array by optional casting to [AnyObject] instead of the cast above to [NSObject: AnyObject]")
        return
    }
    print("Parsed JSON successfully as dictionary: \(JSONDict)")
    // Do stuff with the JSONDict which is a Swift dictionary.
    // For example: let some = JSONDict["key"] as? ValueType will allow you to access the key of the JSONDict
}
catch 
{ 
    // JSON parsing error. 
    print(error) 
}
else 
{ 
     // Error task wasn't created that's unusual unless the URL was bad.
     // Fail here so that you can trace the stack and debug.
     assertionFailure();
}
task.resume()
```

If it doesn't work tell me where it fails and what gets printed to the console.